# How to disable a particular cell inside extjs editor grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an editor grid which has a combobbox, numberfield and a check box. I want to disable the numberfield and the checkbox only for a particular row based on the value selected in the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Even you didn't give any information about which plugin are you using or which version of extjs are you using too, i am gonna give you an advice suppose you are using cellediting plugin. You can use this plugin's events for your purpose. I think you are looking for beforeedit event of cellediting plugin. You can checkout doc [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion beforeedit listener worked